# Set Page Setup Options Programmatically in Classic ASP or ASP.NET

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, activex

So, I inherited this finance reporting web application written in classic ASP and I have been tasked to automatically set the Page Setup in Print Preview so that the page size is automatically set to **Legal** and the orientation is set to **Landscape**.

The web app works in IE7 and uses various ActiveX controls.

Update: is there any way to do this in WScript? I have seen some sample code that does something like the following:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
shell.sendKeys('...');
```

Any suggestions thanks?

Answer (score 1):

I used [meadco scriptx](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/) for control printing setting in IE. It's ActiveX and and clients should install it.